# sum of iid variables: how many terms needed for convergent to normal

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

For sum of iid variables $Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, in general, how large should $n$ be to indicate 'convergence' to normal? 10? 100?

Comment: It converges at $\infty$ for sure. Are you asking for what $n$ that the sum $Z_n$ becomes a "good enough" approximation of a normal distribution? You'd have to decide how close you want this approximation to be or it will always be "a little off".

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [Berry-Esséen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) theorem (and variants, for other metrics: the Berry-Esséen theorem is essentially a quantitative version of the Central Limit Theorem, phrased in terms of Kolmogorov distance between $Z_n$ and the corresponding normal random variable. There are extensions and generalizations, [e.g. to multivariate random variables](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2010/179/) — this link is only one of them).